# JQuery different content for the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 `<p>` tags in my html with the class of `.rule`

I want to change the text of them individually without using separate id's such as `#rule1`, `#rule2`, `#rule3`:

```
$('#rule1').text('Rule 1')
$('#rule2').text('Rule 2')
$('#rule3').text('Rule 3')
```

I just want one class to be selected in JQuery but for it to edit the text of the other `<p>` tags with the same class.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So how will you reference the elements individually? by index?

Comment: What about `myArray = $('rule');` ? With a loop on the array you can set a text for all elements.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :-

```
$('p.rule').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).text("Rule" + (index + 1));
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/d0jwxqxj/)

[Docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: .each() isn't guaranteed to be in order though, is it?

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a function to the `text()` method which will act on each `p` tag individually, with no need to make another method call to `each()`. One of the parameters provided to the function is the index of the element in the matched set. Because of that, you can just return the index appended to a string, like this:

```js
$('p').text(function(i) {
  return 'Rule ' + (i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.foo').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).text("bar " + index);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

You could use a loop to iterate over the DOM-Objects.

Have a look to this https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

This is safer than using the index of the each, since it takes the index relative to the siblings

```js
$('p.rule').text(function() {
  return 'Rule ' + ($(this).index(".rule")+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="rule"></p>
<p class="notrule">Not a rule</p>
<p class="rule"></p>
<p class="rule"></p>
<p class="rule"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to have it hard coded than you can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var rules = $(".rule");
rules.eq(0).text('Rule 1');
rules.eq(1).text('Rule 2');
rules.eq(2).text('Rule 3');
```

other option is to loop over the set with [`.each(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var rules = $(".rule");
rules.each( function (index) {
    $(this).text('Rule ' + index);
});
```

or loop over with [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) with a function

```
var rules = $(".rule");
rules.text( function (index) {
    return 'Rule ' + index;
});
```

Comment: Again that is not necessarily as safe as my suggestion I believe

Comment: @mplungjan If that is what OP needs, sure index() will work, but if it is not, than you have a slower loop. (And I did not see your answer since I took my drinking my hot coffee so I did not burn my tongue as I typed.)

Comment: And yes I know it will be `Rule 0`, hopefully OP know how to add one to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through each p tag using below code. If you have clear idea that of how p tag should be manipulated then it is good else you need to use separate Id's or rely on the order in which your P tags appear.

```
$('p.rule').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).html("P with index" + (index) );// you can accordingly add html or any other jquery operation based on order/index of your p tag
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('p').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).text('Rule ' + (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: Identical to @Kartikeya's

Comment: dont comment before you check the result of my code and the result of Kartikeya's code

Rule 1  not same as Rule1

Comment: Come on... This is the same code. A space does not make a difference to the logic, neither does the use of single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowIndx.

```js
var rowIndx = this.id.substring(this.id.length,this.id.length - 1 );

$("p.rule"+rowIndx).each(function(i){
  
  $(this).text("rule" + (i+1));
  
 });
```